# When action dispatched multiple sage is being callled - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, redux-saga

When an action is dispatched multiple sagas is being called.

I have a component inside a formArray which is connected to a saga. So i think it because of the saga is connected multiple times when the component is used inside a formArray or in a loop.

Form.js

```
  <FieldArray
          name="GLAccounts"
          component={FormGlAccountField}
   />
```

FormGlAccountField.js

```
return (
  <div className="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col- ">
    {hideLabel && <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label>}

    <input
      {...input}
      on="true"
      list={`${input.name}_List`}
      className={touched && error ? `${className} error` : className}
      onKeyUp={handleInputChange}
      onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      placeholder="Code"
      autoComplete="off"
    />
    <datalist id={`${input.name}_List`}>
      {options &&
        options.map(item => (
          <option key={item.id} value={item.acct_code}>
            {item.acct_name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </datalist>
  </div>
);

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
 );

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'GlAccountSelectField', reducer 
});
 const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'GlAccountSelectField', saga });

  export default compose(
   withReducer,
   withSaga,
   withConnect,
  )(GlAccountSelectField);
```

So how to handle this situation

Comment: Why don't you move the saga up to the parent so it's injected only once?